# Sequelize Postgres - Select fields not in groupby

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, sequelize.js

```
Offer.findAll({
  where: {
    userId: id
  },
  attributes: [
    "productDetailId",
    "id",
    "createdAt",
    "userId",
    [Sequelize.fn("MAX", Sequelize.col("offerPrice")), "offerPrice"]
  ],
  group: ["productDetailId"],
  include: [
    {
      model: ProductDetail
    }
  ]
})
```

I have the above `sequelize` query, which aims to find the `offer` with the maximum `offerPrice`for each `ProductDetail` and group the results by `productDetailId`. The above works in `mysql` but throws an error in `postgres`. I suspect this is because the `select` statement contains fields which are not in the `group by`, which is not allowed by `postgres`, but I'm not sure how to update this.

UPDATE:

Error Message:

```
error": {
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
      "name": "error",
      "length": 169,
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "code": "42803",
      "position": "43",
      "file": "parse_agg.c",
      "line": "1388",
      "routine": "check_ungrouped_columns_walker",
```

Comment: could you please share the error that you receive which executing this query?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and grouping by all columns in select was not a case.

You need to group by column using its name with table name, so

```
...
group: ["productDetail.productDetailId"],
...
```